# Change event bus in CDK without deleting stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

We are using the AWS CDK and have several lambda functions in different stacks, that rely on several event buses that are all within the same stack.

Stack 1 --> EventBus Stack

Stack 2 --> EventBus Stack

Stack 3 --> EventBus Stack

We sometimes have to change the event bus source and in turn, we have to delete the event bus stack. The problem is that to delete the event bus stack we have to delete all of the stacks that depend on it.

My question is is there a way to avoid having to delete all stacks that depend on the event bus, or is our implementation fundamentally flawed and we should put an event bus in every stack? We have tried to just do an update to the event bus stack but it gives us errors.

Comment: How do they depend at code level? Smth like `stack1.busArn = eventBusStack.eventBus1.arn`? If so then you can use `ssm.StringParameter` to pass values from EventBusStack to other stacks. It will break export/import dependency and will allow event bus stack deletion without deleting other stacks.

Comment: "or is our implementation fundamentally flawed and we should put an event bus in every stack?" - better to group resources which solve some problem into single stack. `S3Stack`, `DynamoStack` etc make no sense.

Comment: We are creating rules and topics within the EventBusStack. We then have other stacks with lambdas that subscribe to the created topics.

We do this because we have change events on objects from external sources and want to be able to feed that change to one or multiple stacks. Essentially the topics are not owned by one singular function stack. All stacks subscribe to them, so we put them in the eventBusStack.

Comment: IMO, there should be single stack which has 1 lambda, 1 bus, 1 rule to connect bus to lambda. Anyway, even with your current design you can use SSM params to decouple stacks.